# Quartz scheduler clustered

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I'm trying to understand how quartz scheduler works in a clustered environment. I believe pointing the multiple instances of the scheduler app to the same DB and also setting `isClustered=true` will make sure only one scheduler fires the job at the same time. However, I have the following questions:

1. Who ensures that only one scheduler executes the job and how?
2. Can two scheduler instances have the same name (`ids` are `auto`, so I guess they will be distinct? (`org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler`)
3. Who sets DB parameters like next fire time?
4. Ideally, should any of the 11 or so predefined tables (`QRTZ_TRIGGERS`) be populated? Or they are populated based on the beans in the application upon on app startup?

Comment: DB will ensures that only one scheduler executes the job. when a task runs in one node the task in db will updated and changes as running in a node. so other nodes don't runt that again

Comment: 1) Quartz ensures that. Also the job needs to be annotated as DisAllowConcurrentExecution if you want only one instance to be run at a given time.
2) In clustered mode you will have all servers having the same name so that they are grouped together
3) Based on the job schedule quartz takes care of that.
4) Nope. Once app starts up quartz will populate them.